# Can't try import component with alias name for NPM module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, alias

I created a component for `NPM` and tried using its subfolder by importing to another project

I want to use it like this:

```
import {Tab} from '@components/Tabs'
```

Tried to do it in webpack.config next:

```
"@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/components"),
"@components-2": path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
```

then did yarn build
and publish to NPM

but this construction is **not** working.

if I next do the following, it is working fine

```
import {Tabs} from 'components';
let {Tab} = Tabs;
```

I used RCA 2.0 ejected

Main export index.file looks like following:

```
import Component1 from "./Component1 ";
import Component2 from "./Component2";
import * as Tabs from "./Tabs";
export { Component1 , Component2, Tabs };
```

index.js Tab file looks like following:

```
export { default as Tab } from "./Tab";
export { default as TabPanel } from "./TabPanel";
export { default as Tabs} from "./Tabs";
```

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'component/Tabs/Tab' in '...'

It's trying to find this component locally